# Routes conflict with each other only now with Vite 5 build in production

Tags: build, vite, sveltekit

After migrating to SvelteKit 2, which requires Vite 5, I am unable to build the project on the public server. I encounter the error stating:

`The "/" and "/(home)" routes conflict with each other`

This was not an issue before with SvelteKit 1.x and Vite 4, nor is it an issue with the current setup when using `npm run dev` on localhost.

I am able to reproduce the error on localhost if I a `+page.svelte` file in the `/` (route) folder, but I don't need it as there is always a child route, be that `/(home)`, `/(home)/(forms)` or `/(user)` to fill the `<slot />` in the `+layout.svelte` file in `/`.

I noticed that if there are no child routes to a given route then `+page.svelte` file is required, even empty. Could Vite 5 now be 'filling in' and adding the code if it sees a `+page.svelte` missing during `build`, thereby causing the conflict?